# fix time complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity, time

Write an efficient function in the Python language called SmartSearch, this function will receive a sorted arr array of integers of size n containing beginning "yes significant numbers" and the rest of the numbers are "fictitious numbers" whose value is 9999. As the number of functions receive x to search in the array.
Date and the number is in the array, the function must return its index (position), information and the number x does not exist, it must return 1-.
Important note: the size m is unknown.
Required efficiency: O(logm)
Hey
Attaching the code I wrote, I don't know how to improve it for logm
Would appreciate help!
I know I need to do 2 times logm
but does not succeed:

def smartSearch(arr, x):
if arr[0] == 9999 and x!= 9999:
return -1

```
n = len(arr) 
low = 1
while low < n and arr[low] != 9999:
    low *= 2

high = low
low = 0

while low <= high:
    mid = (high + low) // 2

    if arr[mid] ==9999
    
    if arr[mid] == x:
        return mid
    elif arr[mid] < x:
        low = mid + 1
    else:
        high = mid - 1

return -1
```

Comment: [State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  Edit the question with a meaningful title.

Comment: As you may have noticed, the code in your question does not render properly.  Please read the [help page for editing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), then edit the question to add code fences around the code.

Comment: Please clean up your question before we can review it. Does the code produce the correct result?

Comment: the code produce the correct result